# Що таке "движель" на банкноті 20 гривень?

Tags: значення-слів

Отже, на банкноті маємо цитату:

> Земле, моjа всеплодьушчаjа мати! Сили, шчо в твоjіj **движель** глубіні,
>   Крапльу, шчоб в боjу сміліjше стоjати, даj і міні!

Що вдалося знайти про уривок? [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/20_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C) пояснює, що на купюрі він поданий правописом драгоманівкою. [Стилізація](https://uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5,_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8...) сучасним правописом замість **движель** дає нам **живе**, що добре укладається в строфу, але не пояснює движель.

Пошук виводить на питання, створені на різних ресурсах, але такі, що не мають відповіді.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [Етимологічному словнику](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) знаходимо твірне слово до **движель-двигати**:

[image]

[image]

І отже, за Іваном Франком -сили, які рухають в твоїй глибині.

За [народним  прислів'ям](http://vidpoviday.com/prislivya-ta-prikazki-pro-sport-i-zdorovij-sposib-zhittya):

> Рух-життя

тому недивно, що стилізація сучасним правописом замість **движель** дає нам **живе**.

Отже, у цьому випадку **движель**- двигун сил, той що рухає сили.

Comment: Зробив картинки дещо меншими. Дещо негарно вийшло, тому що imgur не дозволяє робити довільне обмеження по ширині, і тому дві картинки вийшли різної ширини. Але хоча-б не так багато місця на екрані займають…

Comment: @Sasha, Дякую за нагадування, fixed. Тепер картинки однакові по ширині і невеличкого розміру.